# .htaccess rewrite from base (http://domain.com/catch-this)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wonder how I should do accomplish the following.

Catch URL's like the following:
http://domain.com/blue-boats send to myfile.php?header=1$

I **don't** want it to have this structure: http://domain.com/boats/blue-boats

I've tried this, but it doesn't work properly:

```
RewriteRule /$ myfile.php?header=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

just put .htaccess in the documentroot of http://domain.com/ with similiar content to the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/?$ /myfile.php?page=$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately that doesn't work. Gets "Page not found". I have a myfile.php in right folder, just printing out "Test" to se if it works and that doesn't show up.

Comment: If you are not doing it on top level you must also set rewritebase as your sirectory name like RewriteBase /mydir/ and also try to change first slash in rewriterule to optional. Add a ? after first slash like it's done for the last one

Comment: It's all in the root/public_html (sorry for confusing). Have done rewrite's earlier. Just don't get the pattern for getting it like "http://domain.com/blue-boats" with no "category"-part like "http://domain.com/boats/blue-boats"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule (.+) myfile.php?header=$1
```